# How do I delineate an empty cell in an array using curly brackets in Google Sheets? (aka Why can't I use "{ , ; "" , "" } In Google Sheets?)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I've found that when I use an array to produce two columns in Google Sheets, it doesn't count the cell in the rightmost column as "empty", and therefore doesn't do the proper "Overflow" text wrapping as it normally would (Text in the left-most column gets truncated instead of overflowing into the next cell)

I've tried various ways to get an empty cell, but none of them have worked:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ "5.2a Comments on ..." , "" ; "" , "Yes (N=_" }) #Doesn't work, and shouldn't work, because "" is not the same as an empty cell.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula works - the text in the cell on the left correctly overflows into the right on my test sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ "5.2a Comments on ..." , IF(1>2,"1>2",) ; "" , "Yes (N=_" })
```

UPDATE: This passes the "ISBLANK()" test, but in my working environment the text still cuts off.

UPDATE 2: I figured out what the problem is, I think: the text cuts off in my working environment because Google Sheets doesn't seem to be able to let text overflow into (or out of) a merged cell.

I'll go off and search for a workaround for that now:-)

In the meantime, if anyone has a more beautiful solution to delineating an empty cell than using `IF(1>2,"1>2",)`, let me know. :-)